# change shape of array so it plots colour matplotlib matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix, matplotlib, wxpython

```
hl = [(1,109),(12,212),(21,23)]
highlightc = np.zeros([N, N])
c = len(highlightc)
colour = [0.21]*c
test = len(number_list) -c

this = [0.21]*test
colour.extend(this)
colour = np.array(colour)
colour = np.array(colour)
print len(number_list)
print colour

for x, y in hl:
    highlightc[x, y] = 1##set so binary matrix knows where to plot
h=ax.imshow(highlightc*colour), interpolation='nearest',cmap=plt.cm.spectral_r)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

I am trying to create a binary matrix, where the plots are different colours. However at the moment I have a problem as they arrays are not the same shape, so the colour does not get plotted. I get the error  `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (160,160) (241)`
I'm guessing that the (160*160) is the size of the matrix and the 241 is the size of the colour array.
I have an array of coordinates that I turned into a binary array `highlightc`. This plots successfully. However with the colour I got the size of the coordinate array, and used that to populate an array to make the colours. Which is obviously wrong. Basically what I want is a certain amount be `0.21` and the rest be `1.0`. So how can I turn the array I have got so it has the shape `(160,160)` so it colours the correct plots in the correct color

Comment: You'll have more chance of getting a good answer if your code is complete. i.e. if I can copy-paste and run it without trying to guess what your data and import statements are. If you have to put in fake or random data that's fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
highlightc = np.ones([N, N])
for x, y in hl:
    highlightc[x, y] = .21 ##set so binary matrix knows where to plot
h=ax.imshow(highlightc*colour), interpolation='nearest',cmap=plt.cm.spectral_r, vmin=0, mvax=1)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

is all you need.

`highlgihtc` will contain `1` everywhere but a few places where it will be `0.21`.